# Question is about the data in the paper: "A Comprehensive Look at The Empirical Performance of Equity Premium Prediction"

Tags: equities, asset-pricing, prediction

I would like to ask a question if you download the data from the Amit Goyal website:
http://www.hec.unil.ch/agoyal/

You will see that there are two columns "CRSP_SPvw"  "CRSP_SPvwx", they are represent the equity premium. But what is the difference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRSP_SPvw includes dividends and CRSP_SPvwx excluding dividends.